# Create and remove image at certain coordinates on android

Tags: android, layout, imageview, coordinates

I have an XML Relative layout, with just a few textviews and buttons on it. But I would like to place an image (or sometimes multiple copies of the image) at different x and Y coordinate which is worked out later on.

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to create the ImageView in android (besides XML) and make it appear at the desired coordinate.

Also it would be great if I could help in making it disappear or removing it at a later stage as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `ImageView` programmatically with `ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);` Then you have to set the LayoutParameters for the view. If you plan to add the view to a RelativeLayout you must use [RelayiveLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). So you can have to do the same as you know from xml: add layout rules. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Then overall something like this:

```
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);

    RelayiveLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     // TODO set the params
     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);


    iv.setLayoutParams(params);
    relativeLayout.addView(iv);
```

To hide the imageView you can user `imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`